# Regex: Get nth character between two delimiters

Tags: regex, oracle11g, regular-language

I have an example string

> 1836248_NNY_01.pdf

but it can also be

> 18362481_YYN_102.pdf

And I need to get the nth character between the two underscores.

So far my regex is `\_(.*?)\_` to get the characters between the underscores. But following up I can't figure out how to get the 2nd N for example.

https://regex101.com/r/XUMKyf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\_.{1}(.).*\_` and replace the `1` with whatever you want.
So `0` would be the first char, `1` the second, and so on.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/XUMKyf/3